# How to convert Unicode strings to ISO?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, iso

Help please, I have to print unicode strings caming from a database (oracle stored procedure => mapping into a java object) into a JSP page (with stuts1), I used this :

```
String unicodeStr = myBean.getTitle();//return from database the unicode string (something like this : Uygulama g\u00fcvenli\u011fi ile).
String isoString = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(unicodeStr);
```

my problem is that the `unicodeStr` came with `"\\"` for each `"\"` (`Uygulama g\\u00fcvenli\\u011fi ile`) so my `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml` can not detect unicode caracters like `"\u00fc"` because of the `"\"` in the begining.

I tried `unicodeStr.replaceAll("\\","\")`, but it can't compile since the `"\"` is not allowed in string without escapement.

Comment: What is this "ISO" thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that in the database the strings are all stored in the Java escaped variant why don't you simply decode them before escaping them to Html?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

String unicodeEscapedStr = myBean.getTitle();
String unicodeStr = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(unicodeEscapedStr);
String isoString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(unicodeStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried unicodeStr.replaceAll("\","\"), but it can't compile since the "\" is not allowed in string without escapement.

You can replace the double backslashes like this:

```
System.out.println("Uygulama g\\u00fcvenli\\u011fi ile".replaceAll("\\\\\\\\","\\"));
```

and it yields:

```
Uygulama g\u00fcvenli\u011fi ile
```

You can find an explanation [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) (see paragraph *Regular Expressions, Literal Strings and Backslashes*):

> In literal Java strings the backslash is an escape character. The literal string "\" is a single backslash. In regular expressions, the backslash is also an escape character. The regular expression \ matches a single backslash. This regular expression as a Java string, becomes "\\". That's right: 4 backslashes to match a single one.
>
> The regex \w matches a word character. As a Java string, this is written as "\w".
>
> The same backslash-mess occurs when providing replacement strings for methods like String.replaceAll() as literal Java strings in your Java code. In the replacement text, a dollar sign must be encoded as \$ and a backslash as \ when you want to replace the regex match with an actual dollar sign or backslash. However, backslashes must also be escaped in literal Java strings. So a single dollar sign in the replacement text becomes "\$" when written as a literal Java string. The single backslash becomes "\\". Right again: 4 backslashes to insert a single one.